# Subreport JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need to develop a report in Jasper-Report which contains a lot of sub-reports. I 'll give you an example what I need:

Master Report:
- Title
- Subreport (1)
- Footer

```
Subreport (1)
    - Table_1 (One time)
    - Table_2 (Could be repeated a lot of time)
    - Table_3 (One time)
```

I need to repeat the Table_2 and Subreport(1) a lot of time, and I don't to know how can I done. I hope had explained clear.
Thanks

Comment: Your problem is resumed to "how to deal with bands". There are good documentation about it on the internet. You should bring a more specific problem, and your title is also too broad.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make three **Detail Bands** in Subreport (1).
2. Create three new subreports: Subreport_Table_1, Subreport_Table_2, Subreport_Table_3.
3. Put Subreport_Table_1 in **Detail Band 1**; put Table 1 in Subreport_Table_1.
4. Put Subreport_Table_2 in **Detail Band 2**; put Table 2 in Subreport_Table_2.
5. Put Subreport_Table_3 in **Detail Band 3**; put Table 3 in Subreport_Table_3.

This results in:

```
Master Report
  Subreport (1)
    Detail Band 1 - Subreport Table 1
      Table 1
    Detail Band 2 - Subreport Table 2
      Table 2
    Detail Band 3 - Subreport Table 3
      Table 3
```

Now you can control the number of times Table 2 is printed independently of Table 1 and Table 3.

Comment: Sorry, i was not so clear. I need to print the Table 2 more than once. Can I print more than one time a Subreport? Can you give an example. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Nicopuri: For the `suberport_table_2` report, change the SQL query to cause the report to run as many times as you need. This will result in the table printing many times.

Answer (score 1):

Nicopuri this is the answer for your comment

For printing subreport more than once your main report's sql query should return more than one row. Then put your subreport in a detail band in your main report.

For example lets say your query result is like below

```
| id |  name  |
| 1  |  bla   |
| 2  |  bla2  |
```

think main report as a loop which is looping 2 times. and detail band as the inside of that loop. so detail band will be evaluated 2 times.